# Call method when value is changed of Qt dynamic property

Tags: c++, qt

I have dynamically added a property to an object using
`this->setProperty("FOV", QVariant(54));` How do I tell it to call a method when the value of this property is changed as in when I update it in my program interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) on QObject instances.

```
class Watcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Watcher(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) 
    {
    }

signals:
    void propertyChanged();

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    { 
        if(event->type()==QEvent::DynamicPropertyChange) 
        {
            QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent *const propEvent = qobject_cast<QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent*>(event);
            // see comment, static_cast should also work and be faster
            // in case of static_cast you don't need to check propEvent to be not null
            if(propEvent)
            {
                // did not test that, but it should work:
                QString propName = QString::fromAscii(propEvent->propertyName().data());
                if ( propName == "FOV")
                {
                    // emit signal to notify specific property was changed
                    emit propertyChanged();
                }
            }
        } 
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};

//...
QObject *const objectToWatch = ...;
QObject *const whoWantToBeNotified = ...;
QObject *const watcher = new Watcher(objectToWatch);
whoWantToBeNotified->connect(
    watcher, 
    SIGNAL(propertyChanged()), 
    SLOT(onPropertyChanged()));
objectToWatch->installEventFilter(watcher);

//...
```

Comment: `qobject_cast<QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent*>(event);` - static_cast is faster. And it's guranteed by Qt core, that it will be successfull.

Comment: Why `qobject_cast` does not pick the fastest and safest cast method automatically?

Comment: because `qobject_cast` is runtime operation, but `static_cast` is compile-time.